# How to fill the value into a new column based on the condition of another column in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
A   B   C   Desired col C
1   Null    Null    C
2   AB  Null    Null
3   AB  Null    Null
4   AB  Null    Null
5   AB  Null    Null
6   AB  Null    Null
7   AB  Null    Null
8   AB  Null    Null
9   AB  Null    Null
1   Null    Null    C
0   Null    Null    C
1   Null    Null    C
1   Null    Null    C
1   Null    Null    C
```

Hi everyone, I created a NaN value column C trying to fill with values as C based on the condition `df['A']<2`. Not sure how to do it.

Desired col c is the format I need.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try using `np.where`:

```
df['Desired col C'] = np.where(df['A'].lt(2), 'C', 'Null')
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
    A     B     C Desired col C
0   1  Null  Null             C
1   2    AB  Null          Null
2   3    AB  Null          Null
3   4    AB  Null          Null
4   5    AB  Null          Null
5   6    AB  Null          Null
6   7    AB  Null          Null
7   8    AB  Null          Null
8   9    AB  Null          Null
9   1  Null  Null             C
10  0  Null  Null             C
11  1  Null  Null             C
12  1  Null  Null             C
13  1  Null  Null             C
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Can you provide what syntax It here?

Comment: @one_random_python_learner I have a condition `df['A'].lt(2)`, which is the same thing as `df['A'] < 2`, and if that is true, it puts `C` in that row, if that is False, it puts `null` in that row, check out more here for `np.where`https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html